# Doctrine array field with default value

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is there a way to set a default value to an array field?

```
data:
    type: array
    nullable: true
    options:
        default: {key1: value1, key2: value2}
        comment: 'Some array data'
```

It would be good to `doctrine:migration:diff` command also set this value in migration.

Comment: You can use Entity `constructor` to assign any default value. That way, the default value will be set for all new Entities.

Comment: Or in the property declaration, like `protected $data = ['foo', 'bar']`